# Why after recreating vm in gcp via terraform some roles are dropping?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-iam

I use some resource to give role to the host, such as

- google_compute_instance_iam_member
- google_compute_instance_iam_binding

When i change hostname of host in terraform, host go to recreating (which is okay), but role dropping (no matter how you did it, member or binding)

I am experiencing an issue with Terraform and Google Cloud Compute Engine resources. Here is the relevant part of my Terraform configuration:

```
resource "google_compute_disk" "root_test_iam" {
  name  = "root-test-iam"
  zone  = local.backend_zone
  type  = "pd-ssd"
  size  = 50
  image = "ubuntu-2004-lts"

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = false
  }
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "test_iam" {
  name                      = "test-iam"
  zone                      = local.backend_zone
  machine_type              = "e2-standard-2"
  allow_stopping_for_update = false
  deletion_protection       = false
  hostname                  = "test-member.xxx-yyy.com"

  boot_disk {
    source      = google_compute_disk.root_test_iam.self_link
    auto_delete = false
  }

  network_interface {
    subnetwork = module.network.us_bare_name
    network_ip = google_compute_address.test_iam_internal.address
  }

  service_account {
    email  = google_service_account.backend_machine.email
    scopes = ["cloud-platform"]
  }

  advanced_machine_features {
    threads_per_core = 2
  }
}

resource "google_compute_instance_iam_member" "root_iam_group" {
  project       = var.project
  zone          = local.backend_zone
  instance_name = google_compute_instance.test_iam.name
  role          = "roles/compute.osAdminLogin"
  member        = "group:game_backend@xxx.com"
}
```

When I run this configuration for the first time, everything works as expected. The host is created and users from the '`game\_backend@xxx.com'` group are able to access the host.

However, when I change the hostname, the VM gets recreated by Terraform. As a result, the users from the '`game\_backend@xxx.com`' group lose their access!

My expectation was that the users from this group would still have access even after the VM is recreated, but this is not the case. I've observed the same problem when using the 'google_compute_instance_iam_binding' resource.

To restore access, I have to run terraform apply again, which seems strange and inefficient.

Can someone explain why this is happening and how I can prevent the loss of access rights during VM recreation?

Comment: I do not understand the problem you are posting. Note: the instance hostname is set at instance creation. The hostname cannot be changed after the instance is created. Edit your post with better details. Also, show the commands you are running. Are you saying that you must run `terraform apply` twice?

Comment: after recreating instance (for example i wanted to change hostname), resource "root_iam_group" not working anymore until i again do "terraform apply"
i have CI which is doing : terraform lint, terraform plan, terraform apply.
So to enable access to instance i should start my CI second time

Comment: Show the logs of each `terraform apply`. I am wondering if you have discovered a bug with Terraform or with your CI.